# How to fix $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: symbols, mathbb

I am writing a code in overleaf with the XeLaTeX compiler.
this is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bidi}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\begin{RTL}
$\mathbb{R}$
\end{RTL}
\end{document}
```

I know that I "should" write the minimal version of the code, but I need to use all of this packages for my work, and so I want a solution that will not clash with the other packages.

When I compiler the code, I get:
[image]

But I want to get the regular:
[image]

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Command `\eth' already defined.`

Comment: The R you get come from Latin Modern Math. But you load Times as text font. Maybe you want to use TeXGyre Termes Math or some other math font that goes well with the Times font for text? If you want to stay with something that is similar to Latin Modern Math, then maybe New Computer Modern Math could be something for you.

Comment: @mickep The thing is I already used all those packages multiple times and nothing like this ever happend

Comment: don't use any of `\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}` with `unicode-math` (`unicode-math` loads `amsmath` and the others are not compatible with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The R you show is not a problem it is the design from latin modern math which is the default font once you select unicode-math, here I use Stix Two which is far more compatible with a Times Roman text font.

I removed the ams packages as they are not compatible with `unicode-math` and give errors.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bidi}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\begin{document}
\showoutput
\begin{RTL}
$\mathbb{R}$
\end{RTL}
\end{document}
```

Another Times compatible math font that has black board bold perhaps closer to your request is TeX Gyre Termes which produces

[image]

from

```
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
```

Comment: But is the unicode-math package include all of the amsmath, amsfonts and amssymb stuff?

Comment: @ArielFishbein it literally includes amsmath.sty and amsfonts/amssymb make no sense with it as they are loading 8 bit legacy tex math fonts and the whole point of unicode-math is to use opentype. It already covers a larger set of characters with mostly compatible command names.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the only problem: if you try

```
$\mathbb{R}+x+y+z$ \textit{xyz} $x$\textit{x}
```

you not only get a blackboard bold letter you don't like, but also clashing fonts between text and math:

[image]

In order to get a math font compatible with Times New Roman you could choose STIX Two Math, but, again the blackboard bold is probably not of your liking. You can replace the blackboard bold block, though, with another font that has the glyphs you like.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bidi}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[range=\mathbb,Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase,range=]

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{R}+x+y+z$ \textit{xyz} $x$\textit{x}

\end{document}
```

The last instruction with `range=` is used to reinstate the font parameters of STIX Two Math. You might just use TeX Gyre Termes Math for everything, but it's way less complete than the other font.

[image]

Note that `amssymb` and `amsfonts` should not be loaded together with `unicode-math`.